# Solving a differential equations with initial condition (piecewise function)

Tags: differential-equations

My code:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x^2, x >= 1}}]

DSolve[{y D[u[x, y], x] + x D[u[x, y], y] == x y, u[x, 0] == f[x]}, 
  u[x, y], {x, y}] // FullSimplify
```

Why in out[37] appears that? it's bad? thanks you.

[image]

Comment: It' not bad, solution is a piecewise complex function.

Comment: fyi, this is what Maple gives. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Lf5.png)   may be there is a way to simplify Mathematica's result (with the right kind of assumptions) to match. Try `PiecewiseExpand` and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

To long for a comment, perhaps the answer:

Maple solution(thanks to @Nasser's comment) follows somewhat awkwardly

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x^2, x >= 1}}]

U = Values@DSolve[{y D[u[x, y], x] + x D[u[x, y], y] == x y, u[x, 0] == f[x]}, u , {x, y} ]  [[1, 1]]
```

$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{2} \left(y^2+2 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 -i \sqrt{y^2-x^2} & 0\leq -i \sqrt{y^2-x^2}\leq 1 \\
 x^2-y^2 & -i \sqrt{y^2-x^2}\geq 1 \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right)$

Solution is real valued if `x^2-y^2>0`

```
((U[x, y] /.  x^2 -> y^2 + pos^ 2) // Simplify[#, pos > 0] &) /.pos -> Sqrt[x^2 - y^2]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 x^2-y^2 & \sqrt{x^2-y^2}>1 \\
 \sqrt{x^2-y^2} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right)+\frac{y^2}{2}$